# I can't get any nodes from GoogleMap component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing-library

I wanna test my map component. I'm using react-testing-library with Jest. I don't know how to get any nodes from `<GoogleMap></GoogleMap>` (This component is too deep). I've tried get marker and remove button, but It doesn't work. I added comment near remove button (easier to search). Can someone give me any tips?

```
export const MapWithAMakredInfoWindow = compose(
  withProps({
     googleMapURL: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${apiKey}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`,
     containerElement: ( ... ),
     withStateHandlers( ... ),
     withScriptjs,
     withGoogleMap,
     lifecycle({
      componentDidMount() {
      const refs = {};
      this.setState(...)
)(props => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      ...props
    >
      {props.indicators
        .filter( ... )
        .map((indicator, index) => {
          return (
            <Marker
              data-testid="marker" // I cannot get it
              ...props
            >
              {props.isOpen &&
                props.id === indicator.id && (
                  <InfoBox
                    ...props
                  >
                    <InfoBoxContainer>
                      <InfoContent>{indicator.name}</InfoContent>
                      <InfoContent>{indicator.street}</InfoContent>
                      <InfoContent>{indicator.city}</InfoContent>
                      <InfoContent>{indicator.country}</InfoContent>
                      <InfoBtn onClick={() => props.remove(indicator.id)} data-testid="removeBtn"> //it doesn't work
                        Remove Marker
                      </InfoBtn>
                    </InfoBoxContainer>
                  </InfoBox>
                )}
            </Marker>
          );
        })}
```

```
export class Map extends Component {

  constructor(props) {...}
  componentDidMount() {...}
  addIndicator = (event, geocode) => {...};
  remove = id => {...};
  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <MapWithAMakredInfoWindow
          ...
        />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```